# Where can I get OneDrive MSA Authenticator?

Tags: java, onedrive

Official guide says that I should get a OneDriveClient to perform opertaions with OneDrive API, but I can not find where I can get MSA Authenticator for my app. I followed all instructions, but there is only Client ID that fits ADAL Authenticator and no MSA. So, where can I get it?
Proof that there is no MSA Auth is here: 
[Application Registration Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPddX.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusing document. There was an update on the Microsoft developer portal where they adopted new MSA client ID in GUID format which is the same as AAD client ID. You should be safe to put the GUID format MSA ID in MSA Authenticator. I updated the document on [Github](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android) as well.